# Highlight a row on hover not working without !important

Tags: html, css

Here's the table in my html file. I was trying the hover effect but it's not working without the !important.

```
<tr ng-repeat="case in lastten" ng-click="setSelected(case.BuildName)" ng-class="{selected: case.Name === idSelectedVote}">
    <td colspan="1">{{case.Name}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{case.Total}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{case.Passed}}</td>
    <td colspan="1">{{case.Failed}}</td>
</tr>
```

css- If i remove the !important .It won't work.

```
table {
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #f3f7fb;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background: #ffffff;
}

tr:hover td {
  background: #eee !important;
}
```

Comment: which .js file you including in your html..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the background color the td using two different selectors. `table tr:nth-child(even) td` takes higher precedence over `tr:hover td`. Set the alternating bg color of the tr and on hover you can set the bg color of the td.

Alternatively you can use the following selector to increase the precedence of hover selector

```
tr:nth-child(n):hover td {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```css
table {
    width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;

}

table tr:nth-child(even){
  background: #f3f7fb;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ffffff;
}

    tr:hover td {
      background: #eee;
    }
```

```html
<table><tr ng-repeat="case in lastten" ng-click="setSelected(case.BuildName)" ng-class="{selected: case.Name === idSelectedVote}">

                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Name}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Total}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Passed}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Failed}}</td>


                        </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="case in lastten" ng-click="setSelected(case.BuildName)" ng-class="{selected: case.Name === idSelectedVote}">

                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Name}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Total}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Passed}}</td>
                            <td colspan="1">{{case.Failed}}</td>


                        </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `:nth-child` selector specify value is bigger than base's specify value.

In other words, `table tr:nth-child(odd) td`'s specify value is bigger than `table tr td`. So on hover, `tr td` is ignored. because `table tr:nth-child(odd) td` has background color `#ffffff`.

If use `!important` syntax, it makes specify value maximum value. so it works.